# One method induces a segfault, the other doesn't. What is the difference?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

My source code contains a segment similar to the following:

```
double ****A;

my_function(A);
```

which throws a segfault error in my_function.

However, when I replace it with:

```
double ***A;

my_function(&A);
```

then my_function works. I would have thought my_function would see the same argument in both cases.

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: what's `my_function`, show more code pls

Comment: Can we reduce it to one star? I don't see a point of the extra three.

Comment: Please don't post romantic code ("similar to the following"). Post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: My question pertained to general C syntax, not to where I am going wrong in my original source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This: `double ****A;` is not set to point to anything. It is a dangling pointer with no known value.

This: `double ***A; double ****B = &A;` which is kind of what your function call does, points B at the storage of A, so the pointer actually points to something that exists.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
double ****A;

my_function(A);
```

and assuming that those lines appear literally in your code, with no value assigned to `A`, we can be sure that you're passing an uninitialized value, a garbage pointer, to `my_function`. That in itself has undefined behavior. Whether it causes a segmentation fault will depend on what `my_function` does with that value.

This:

```
double ***A;

my_function(&A);
```

passes a valid value of type `double****`. That value is the address of a declared object. By itself, the call is perfectly valid. (It might result in a segmentation fault depending on what `my_function` does with it, but you haven't shown us what `my_function` does, so I won't speculate further.)

EDIT: I just noticed the phrase "similar to the following" in your question. Without seeing your *exact* code, we have no idea what you've left out, and your question is essentially unanswerable. (I wouldn't have posted this answer if I had noticed that initially.)

Comment: My question is not essentially unanswerable, as it has been succinctly answered by both you and Zan Lynx. My question did not pertain to my original code. Instead, it pertained to the code I posted, as I was asking what the difference is between the two snippets I posted above.

Comment: @DJames: I couldn't tell whether you had assigned a value to `A` somewhere between its definition and the call to `my_function`. My answer assumed that you hadn't, but given that the code in your question was merely "similar" to your actual code, there was no way to be sure. Posting a simplified version of your code is encouraged, but it should be actual code that exhibits the problem. See [mcve].